# Implementing set of "foos" which has a subset of "bars" in C#

Tags: c#, oop, casting, object-oriented-analysis

I am writing a server to handle different types of messages from client to host.  The messages are of varying content and length and will be preceded by an identifier to identify what type the message is.  Some messages (of type A, B, and C for instance) should just be forwarded between machines.  Others (of type D, E, and F for instance) require a specific action from the server: ie. they are not just forwarded.

(NOTE: The clients on either end need to differentiate between A, B, and C but the server only needs to know to forward those messages.  Both the server AND the clients need to be able to differentiate between D, E, and F.)

What I am trying to find is a good Object Oriented paradigm for representing the idea of what "type" a message is.  So to clarify, imagine the server receives a messaged labeled as "Type B", it needs to simply forward that to the appropriate client.  However, if it receives a message labeled as "Type F" it will take different, specific, action.  So how could I represent the "Type" in my code?

An ideal solution for what I want to implement would be something like this; and enumeration "Type" in which a certain subset of Commands are of the type "Forwardable".  Obviously that isn't possible so I thought of a static class, Forwardable, that inherits from a base static class, Type.  Again, impossible.  Interfaces could be possible, but I would really rather not have to instantiate instances just to interpret a type.

The most straight forward way of having the server parse the message would be something like this:

```
byte[] payload = GetPayload((byte[])rawMessage);
Type message = GetMessageType((byte[])rawMessage);
if(message is Forwardable)
{
  ForwardMessage(payload);
}
else
{
  switch(message)
   case 1:
     //
     break;
   case 2:
     //
     break;
}
```

So finally, what is the proper OO way of representing a set of Types in which a subset of those Types is a Subtype?

EDIT:
In a way, I feel like this should be done by defining a static class of "Types" and defining another static class that inherits from "Types" called "Forwardable".  I can then cast what my server receives as a "Type" and say if(header is Forwardable).  But unfortunately, you cannot inherit from static classes . . .

Comment: are your messages of the same structure or are they completely different structures? The "proper" way depends on it

Comment: Why are you saying that enumeration of the type is "obviously impossible?"

Comment: They "Type" will be of the same structure.  Right now, I am identifing them as an enumeration.
@David S.: Because enums can't inherit or have specific types.

Comment: I'm asking about the whole message. If they are of the same structure then you can use an enumeration to identify which kind are they and that would be the "proper" way. In case your message structures are different you could either break away a constant "header" and use the first approach or implement a base class + subclasses.  It's not clear from your example because there are no parameters on GetMessageType and GetPayload

Comment: Sten: The whole message is an array of bytes with varying content and length.  The message is preceded by my "Type" which is currently represented as an integer in memory.  How could I use an enumeration if I want different types?  I guess I could have two different enumerations and attempt to cast what I receive as each enumeration?

Comment: I'm confused why do you need two enumerations. If all you need to do is redirect the bytestream differently depending on the first two bytes

Comment: Well I could think of plenty of ways to only look at the first two bytes and make a decision.  But I am looking for a better OO way of doing this.  I have to pass this off to very inexperienced programmers and I need everything in this code to be VERY extensible and easily expandible.  Therefore, I would love to have two types (Forwardable and non) for them to add commands to in the future.  Basically, I don't just want to make this work, I want to make it the best code I can.

Comment: I'm confused why you need 6 types (A,B,C,D,E,F) when you have only two behaviors. You can just have bool which will indicate whether message is forwardable or not.

Comment: @Vajda: I don't only have two behaviors.  The non-forwardable can each have specifica actions needed, and I also need to differentiate between what the server does for forwardable (just forward it) and what the client does.  The client needs to know what to do with that forwarded message.

Comment: Then you need either two methods (GetMessageType and IsMessageForwardable) which will extract info from payload.Or you need  one method which will return Type where you have either implemented Forwardable in half, or have Abstract type with Forwardable bool property which is in half implemented to return true, and in half to return false)

Comment: @Vajda: Precisely. The only problem is, how do I implement Forwardable in half?  Inheritance?  Interfaces?

Comment: I provided an answer, you can look at it for possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea to wrap things up so you can pass them off to others. You can define a MessageType to wrap the entire message loading and identification, PayloadType to wrap all sorts of payload and subclasses - ForwardMessage, ArchiveMessage - to identify different types of payload.

- Message is responsible for taking your original stream input,
- PayloadType is responsible for loading its subclasses and common
  fields, including MessageType
- ForwardMessage, ArchiveMessage are responsible for any business logic and they don't
  have to know anything about loading itself from streams. Implement
  more of these for different types of payload.

Using the sample code:

```
Message msg = Message.FromStream(stream);
PayloadType payload = msg.GetPayload();
payload.Process();
```

Here's the sample code:

```
public class Message{
      public int Prefix {get; private set;}
      public byte[] RawPayload {get;private set;}

      public PayloadType GetPayload(){
        PayloadType result = null;
        switch (Prefix){ // you can also convert that to enum and use "if" for more complicated identification
          case 1: 
            result = PayloadType.FromRaw<ForwardMessage>(RawPayload);
            break;
          case 2: 
            result = PayloadType.FromRaw<ArchiveMessage>(RawPayload);
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }

      public static Message FromStream(Stream s){
        Prefix = ReadTwoBytes(s);
        RawPayload = ReadToEnd(s);
      }
    }

    public abstract class PayloadType{
      public abstract MessageType MessageType {get;} // enum goes better here
      public abstract Process();

      public static T FromRaw(byte[] raw) where T: PayloadType{
        // deserialize this as you wish
        // such as:
        using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(raw)){
          XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
          return xser.Deserialize(s) as T; 
        }
      }
    }

    public ForwardMessage : PayloadType{
      public override MessageType MessageType {return MessageType.Forward;}
      public override Process(){
          // send this message elsewhere
      }
    }

    public ArchiveMessage: PayloadType{
      public override MessageType MessageType {return MessageType.Archive;}
      public override Process(){
           // store this message somehow
      }
    }

    public enum MessageType{
        Unknown, Formward, Archive,
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am just missing something obvious here, but I don't see how this lets multiple messages be of type "ForwardMessage" and also have their own distinct type.  That is, I see that this is useful for managing the difference between Unknown and ForwardMessage.  Is "Prefix" of type "MessageType"?

Comment: @user912447 I added another payload type and an usage sample code, does that make it clearer?

Comment: Ah yes, I understand it.  This is a great OO solution.  The only thing is, you will end up with the same issue as David S's solution.  When you add a new Forwardable type you will have to go an explicitly add it to your switch statement.  This isn't necessarily bad by any means, but I feel that it would be more useful to make it Forwardable in its very definition.  Perhaps this isn't possible in C#, but I might keep looking around a bit.  As far as OO goes though, this is a very impressive solution.

Comment: @user912447 You're right, you'll have to add it to the switch. You can go further and add assembly attributes that map the class type responsible for each message type but that's taking it too far and is less maintainable. And in this case only Message is the class that has to know how to deal with the ID, you can think of it as a Factory. One way or another, regardless of language, you'll have to somehow indicate which type corresponds to what ID and abstracting any further than `switch` or `if`s can make things harder to find

Comment: That's a good point.  Switches and ifs are typically very easy to follow and, for this situation, may provide more of a benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your problem, I would do the following :

- Use an object representation for each message
- Use a pattern like [Chain of responsability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) to handle messages based on their types.

The advantages of this architecture is that you separate the handling logic of each message type. This allow you to extend it (add a new message handler or a new message type) quickly without impacting the rest of the system. Moreover, you can use polymorphism to allow a single handler to handle multiple message types (in your case, a ForwardHandler).

Here's a quick example of implementation.

First, messages types :

```
public abstract class BaseMessage { ... } // base class inherited by every message
public abstract class ForwardableMessage : BaseMessage { ... } // base class for message that should only be forwarded
public class MessageOfTypeA : BaseMessage { ... } // a message of type A (which is not forwardable)
public class MessageOfTypeB : ForwardableMessage { ... } // a message of type B (which is forwardable)
public class MessageOfTypeC : ForwardableMessage { ... } // a message of type C (which is forwardable)
```

(Note that it might be more flexible in this case to use an interface for the forwardable messages, I would be interested in people opinion on this matter).

Second, define your handlers :

```
public abstract class BaseMessageHandler {

    public abstract bool CanHandle(BaseMessage msgToHandle)
    public abstract void Handle(BaseMessage msgToHandle);

}

public class MessageForwarderHandler : BaseMessageHandler {

    public bool CanHandle(BaseMessage msgToHandle)
    {
        return msgToHandle is ForwardableMessage;
    }

    public void Handle(BaseMessage msgToHandle)
    {
        // do the forwarding logic here
    }

}

public class MessageOfTypeAHandler : BaseMessageHandler {

    public bool CanHandle(BaseMessage msgToHandle)
    {
        return msgToHandle is MessageOfTypeA;
    }

    public void Handle(BaseMessage msgToHandle)
    {
        // do the logic specific to messages of type A
    }

}
```

Finally, you have to implement an object that maintains a list of the different handlers.

```
public static class MessageHandlersProvider
{
    IEnumerable<MessageHandler> handlers = new List<MessageHandler>()
    {
        new MessageOfTypeAHandler(),
        new MessageForwarderHandler()
    }

    public static void HandleMessage(BaseMessage msg)
    {
        foreach (MessageHandler handler in handlers)
        {
            if (handler.CanHandle(msg))
            {
                handler.Handle(msg);
                // you may stop once you have found a handler that can handle or you might consider that multiple handlers can be applied to the same message
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution does indeed require an instance of object for each message but it is, in my opinion far more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
enum ActionType
{
    Forwardable, ....
}

class Message //could be abstract, then make classes A : Message, B: Message etc with appropriate fields
{
    private Byte[] payload;

    public ActionType CurrentActionType {get;private set;}

    public Message(byte[] rawmessage)
    {
        //parse message's header to determine ActionType
        //parse rest of message and save to payload or other variables in inherited classes
    }
}

Message msg = new Message((byte[])rawMessage);
switch(msg.CurrentActionType)
{
    case ActionType.Forwardable :
        ForwardMessage(msg); break;
    case...
    case...
}
```

**Edit**: `ShouldForward` function as discussed in comments:

```
private Boolean ShouldForward(Message msg)
{
    switch(msg.CurrentActionType)
    {
        case ActionType.A:
        case ActionType.B:
        case ActionType.C:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even here, though, I need "Forwardable" to be a subset of a larger group.  Types A, B, and C need to all be forwarded.  The server only needs to know to forward the message, but the clients need to differentiate between A, B, and C.

Comment: @user912447 Could the `ActionType` have members A, B, C, D etc.. which makes it easy for the client, and in the server you have a method `Boolean ShouldForward(Message)` that returns true if message has ActionType A,B or C? If the client doesn't need to know whether message is forwardable I think this is ok in terms of OO.

Comment: Yeah, that could work.  How to implement that function though, is the issue.  I would rather not say something like if(messageType < 5) forwardMessage();

  I would much rather have a more OO approach than that.

Comment: As opposed to explicitly identifying what types of messages should be forwarded I would like to define them as being forwardable.  That is, if I were to add a new forwardable type (G) I would not want to have to declare it as a new message type AND add it to the list of cases in your example.  However, you solution will absolutely work and it fairly elegant.

Comment: @user912447 yeah I see the issue. Consider however, if it is any better to have many more lines/pages declaring inheriting classes in something that can be accomplished in few lines. It wouldn't necessarily make things more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class MsgType
{
  public bool IsForwardable { get; }
}

public class A : MsgType
{
  public override bool IsForwardable
  {
    get { return true; }
  }
}

public class F : MsgType
{
  public override bool IsForwardable
  {
    get { return false; }
  }
}
```

Or second solution:

```
public interface Forwardable
{ }

public class A : Forwardable
{ }

public class F
{ }
```

Or third solution

```
byte[] payload = GetPayload((byte[])rawMessage);
Type message = GetMessageType((byte[])rawMessage);
if(IsForwardable((byte[])rawMessage))
{
  ForwardMessage(payload);
}
else
{
  TakeAppropriateAction(message, payload);
}
```

Comment: That first solution is actually pretty interesting.  It is basically a flag that you set up on defining the class.  It is a little bulkier than an enumeration, in that you need a whole new class for each type of message, but certainly workable.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a class for each processing type (forward, delete, etc) and then decorating them with a custom .NET Attribute + implementing a known interface

```
[MessageProcessor("TypeB")]
public class TypeBMessageProcessor : IMessageProcessor
{
  void IMessageProcessor.Process(byte[] message)
  {
     ....
  }
}
```

You could could then scan your assemblies at app start-up, find classes decorated with your custom MessageProcessorAttribute, and then store the type in a Dictionary keyed by the "TypeB" parameter on the attribute...held by some kind of MessageProcessorFactory class.

You can then create an instance of that type whenever a message comes in to process.

```
var processor = MessageProcessorFactory.GetProcessor("TheTypeCodePrecedingTheData");
processor.Process(messageData);
```

Comment: I like this but I'm not familiar with custom attributes.  Would the "forward" processing type you mentioned be able to contain multiple messages?  Is this solution similar to setting a "Forwardable" bool in each class and then having a new class for each message type?

Comment: The solution I offer has no idea about the message at all, it would just know which message handler to pass it on to.  The processor would have to be able to check if there are multiple messages in there and could possibly use the MessageProcessorFactory to process each of them and then forward them elsewhere.

Comment: .Net attributes are just data decorations for your class.  Your MessageProcessorFactory class initialiser can search all classes using Assembly.GetTypes() and then use LINQ to only give you types decorated with MessageProcessorAttribte.  It's all very easy stuff, I doubt you will struggle with it.